# "Export" a CVS checkout

Tags: export, cvs, checkout

I have a checkout of a CVS repository. The original repository does not exist anymore. Would it be possible to run something similar to "export" on the checkout itself? What I would want to end up with, is the set of all files that came from the checkout, and remove the files that were added afterwards.

Example: I check out superProject, and get

`superProject/checkedoutFile1.txt
superProject/checkedoutFile2.txt
superProject/checkedoutFile3.txt`
And then I add

`superProject/someFile1.txt
superProject/someFile2.txt
superProject/someFile3.txt`
and then I would like to remove all the files that were not in the original checkout.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`cvsu`](http://www.unixref.com/manPages/cvsu.html) does an offline cvs update by comparing the timestamps of files on disk with their timestamps recorded in `CVS/Entries`. You can thus tell which files have been locally modified and which files are not known to be under CVS control.

```
sudo aptitude install cvsutils
cvsu --batch="tar cf export.tar " --types=AFGM
```

Run `cvsu --help` to see supported command line options. This functionality is provided by Perl, and can vary from one machine to another.

On Windows, Cygwin [supports it](http://cygwin.com/packages/cvsutils/).

Answer (score 1):

Just noted your comment and edited my answer accordingly.

My initial answer was: simply remove all directories named "CVS"

Naturally, if more stuff has been added to the checked out directories, you should go a different route. CVS keeps its metadata in a `CVS` subdirectory in each checked out directory. The various files are described on p.16 of the [Cederqvist](http://ftp.gnu.org/non-gnu/cvs/source/stable/1.11.19/cederqvist-1.11.19.pdf) manual.

In your case, the interesting information is kept in the `Entries` file, which has two different line formats:

```
/filename/...other stuff...
D/directory/...filler...
```

The first one for plain files, the second one for directories; there's no particular order.

You could write a script that walks down the directory tree, extracting directory and file names from these `Entries` files. You can feed this list into `cpio -pmdv target-dir` to create a copy of your directory structure, that holds exactly the files, a `cvs export` would have created.

I hope this helps

Comment: There are other files added to the checkout as well.